# Mobile Device Programming Tools

Tags: mobile

What SDKs/Tools/Toolkits/IDEs should I download to start programming mobile applications for iPhone, Symbian and BlackBerry from within Windows platform?

And from where can I download them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the **iPhone** platform, your current option is to become an [iPhone developer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/), use the iPhone SDK and develop on a Mac. The IDE you will most likely use is XCode and the language of development will be Objective-C.

  The [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/) seems to be developing an alternative to this in the form of the [MonoTouch](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch) framework. Using this framework you can develop your iPhone applications in C# using MonoDevelop and they will be compiled to native iPhone applications; however, you still need the iPhone SDK and you still need to develop on a Mac. This framework is in closed preview at the moment, though.
- For **Symbian**, it used to be the case that you needed to develop using the C/C++ libraries provided by the [Symbian SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a7149a5-95a5-4726-913a-3c6f21eb65a5/S60-SDK-0616-3.0-mr.html) but now you have the choice to develop in C++ using the [Qt for S60 toolkit](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/technical-preview-qt-for-s60) (I should note that it is still a technical preview).

  Depending on what you are trying to build, you might want to develop J2ME applications which will work on all Java-enabled phones (thus you won't be limited to just the S60 platform). You can develop such J2ME applications using the [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) plugin for Eclipse.
- For **Blackberry**, the default development environment is the [Blackberry JDE](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp). However, I hate the user interface on that tool and (for me at least) the usability leaves a lot to be desired. However, you have an alternative: There is an official [Blackberry JDE plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp) for the Eclipse IDE that makes developing Blackberry applications a joy (well not so much :) but still makes it really easy)
- In case you are interested, you can develop **Windows Mobile** applications in C# targeting the .NET Compact Framework using Visual Studio (I think you can use the [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/), which is free).
- Then, there is the **Android** platform. The default [development environment](http://developer.android.com/sdk/1.5_r3/index.html) for that platform is using the Android Eclipse plugin and developing in Java.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone sdk](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)

[Symbian](http://developer.symbian.com/main/tools_and_sdks/sdks/)

[Blackberry](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/)

Comment: According to this site windows development is not supported for iPhone. What else can I go for?

Answer (score 0):

For Symbian, I would recommand [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products).
Moreover, you can use it for Windows CE based mobile.

Comment: Is it possible to develop iPhone in windows?